# Force Matlab to echo each comand before displaying answer

Tags: matlab, command-line-interface

In Matlab, `echo on` causes statements in a script or function to be displayed as executed.  If I paste a block of code into the command window, the statements are shown where pasted, but are not echoed before each result is diplayed.  Same with invoking a block of statements from the Command History.  Is there a way to force Matlab to echo each command in the Command Window before displaying each result, even when a block of statements are pasted or recalled from the Command History?

Comment: That would be useful, but I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: You're probably right, but I have my fingers crossed that you are not.  Hope you understand....

Comment: What do you need this for? Have you considered using a [live script](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-live-scripts.html)?